# Как можно получить из таблицы все, что находится после конкретного поля?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Допустим, есть отсортированная таблица

```
ID          CITY     STATE
ea-12       Phoenix  AZ
ds-44       Denver   CO
gr-46       Caribou  ME
cv-66       Sidney   FD
vb-34       Lubec    KF
```

Хочу получить все строки таблицы в том же порядке, которые находятся ниже gr-46:

```
ID          CITY     STATE
cv-66       Sidney   FD
vb-34       Lubec    KF
```

Наиближайшее, что приходит голову: сначала достать номер строки по id gr-46 и воспользоваться offset. Но это выглядит как не очень оптимальный запрос + с большими оффсетами postgres сильно теряет в перфорансе.

Может есть какие-то еще варианты? Подразумевается, что эта выборка будет после сложного запроса с сортировкой, поэтому сохранить порядок - очень важно

Comment: А по какому полю отсортирована эта таблица ? И что такое в принципе "отсортированная таблица", ведь БД не гарантирует порядок строк в выборке пока не указан явный order by

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что таблица перед этим была отсортирована в запросе (SORT BY city, например)

Comment: Если order by city, то надо получить city из записи gr-36, а потом найти все записи у которых city больше чем в этой. т.е. `select * from table where city >= (select city from table where id='gr-36'`